# Make all subdomains point to on single file/folder using ".conf" file

Tags: apache, http-redirect

I wanted to redirect all my subdomain to a single file/folder I done the pointing thing before using .conf files in apache but I did it for a specific domain.

this is the conf file that I use for pointing the domain.

```
listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/dist
    <Directory /var/www/html/project/dist>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but what I want is to redirect all the subdomain to redirect to the same project which has some domain for example:-

currently, the upper conf file will redirect to my project folder but what I want is that if I have domain-like

- sd1.domain.com
- sd2.domain.com
- sd3.domain.com

they should also point to the same project directory. but I am not sure how to do it
thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by doing a slight change into my .conf file here is my new file

```
listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/dist
    <Directory /var/www/html/project/dist>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

what I did I add the server alias to (*) which let me allow to redirect all my subdomain to single project.